# Postman scripts : "pm is not defined"

Tags: postman

I try to write a Pre-request script in Postman. I want to to make a request so I try to use [`pm.sendRequest`](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference#pmsendrequest). For example :

```
pm.sendRequest('http://example.com', function (err, res) {
    //...
});
```

But I get this error :

`There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script: pm is not defined`

I'm on Windows 10. I just updated the extension.

How do I access `pm`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A member posted an answer but, for some reason, I think he got banned. His answer didn't have a lot of details, but was working :

You have to use the [standalone version](https://www.getpostman.com/postman) of Postman for the `pm` to be accessible. I was using it as a *Chrome extensio*n. By switching to the standalone version, it worked. I don't know why, though.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't' realize my installation of PostMan was really old. And yes, it was the Chrome app. After I installed the full standalone version, the pm object works.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running an old version of Postman, you may run into this issue as I did. From https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/test_examples#older-style-of-writing-postman-tests

> The older style of writing Postman tests relies on setting values for the special tests object.

If you are running an older version of Postman, you will not have the pm object available for use.

Answer (score 0):

For extension version, you can use following pattern:

> tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

As per the postman's [official doc](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/#previous-style-of-writing-postman-tests-deprecated), using `postman.*` or `responseBody` are deprecated and were old instructions. So, make sure you are running the latest version of Postman (standalone or chrome extension).

However, if you still face issues with `pm.*`, then proceed below for some help.

**Previous**

If anyone is using the Desktop version of Postman (in my case Mac's desktop version),

Then,

- use `responseBody` instead of `pm.response.text()`
- to set global variable `postman.setGlobalVariable()` instead of `pm.environment.set()`

Sample:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("studentId", jsonData.studentId);
```

You can use `SNIPPETS` to auto-generate basic things like the above to avoid these errors.
[image]

My Postman version detail:

```
Postman for Chrome
Version 5.5.6
OS X / arm64
Chrome 108.0.0.0
```

Comment: I´m also using chrome extension. Is there an equivalent for ```pm.sendRequest```?

Comment: Please make sure that you are running the latest version of the postman.

Refer: [postman doc](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/#previous-style-of-writing-postman-tests-deprecated)

Comment: Below might be helpful for you, 

```var settings = {   "async": true,   "crossDomain": true,   "url": environment.ThirdPartyUrl + "/authorize/refresh/?AppKey=" + environment.ThirdPartyApiKey,   "method": "GET" }; $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {   postman.setGlobalVariable("AccessToken", response.AccessToken); });```


Refer: [medium article](https://mrponath.medium.com/postman-pre-request-scripts-81920a78d0fc)

Answer (score -4):

Replace **pm** with **postman**, it should work fine.

Comment: That causes the error: "postman.sendRequest" is not a function