# How to append data in JSON Query?

Tags: api, postman, web-api-testing

I'm a newbie in using postman as testing web rest API. Can you help me in this simple error? The error says: There was an error in evaluating the test script:  ReferenceError: jsonData is not defined.

Thanks in advance!

```
pm.test("User ID is 1 -> " +jsonData[0].userId, function () {
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(jsonData[0].userId).to.eql(1);
});
```

[image]

Comment: You're using the variable before declaring it - try taking the jsonData part out of the name and trying it. If you move the var line above the function it should work.

Comment: Woah! It works! Thank you @DannyDainton :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the standalone version of postman, or the chrome extension? If you're using the chrome extension, you'll find that `pm` is undefined, [as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46282437/8526705)

Though perhaps not exactly had in mind, if you are working with the chrome extension, you can defined "testing logic" in a slightly different way via the Tests tab:

[image]

The Testing tab allows you to write tests that are automatically run across the response data that returns after your click "Send".

This basically lets you write and execute javascript in Postmans own testing context, allowing you to define some fairly elaborate test logic to verify that your response data returns the expected results:

```
var contentTypeHeaderExists = responseHeaders.hasOwnProperty("Content-Type");

tests["Has Content-Type"] = contentTypeHeaderExists;

if (contentTypeHeaderExists) {
    tests["Content-Type is application/json"] = 
      responseHeaders["Content-Type"].has("application/json");
}
```

See [this blog post](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/03/07/writing-automated-tests-for-apis-using-postman/) for more information on using the Testing tab - hope this helps you!